# Non deprecated way of appending an element to a List in Scala 2.7.5?

Tags: list, scala, deprecated

How do you add an element to a `List` in Scala 2.7.5, without creating a new `List` and without using a deprecated solution.

Comment: Mutation is bad, mmkay  :)

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify if by "without creating a new `List`" you mean not duplicating the whole list in memory, or having all references to the list reflect the change. The latter is not possible, as `List`, in Scala, is immutable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Non deprecated way of appending an
>   element to a List in Scala 2.7.5?

That does not exist, and it will never exist.

> How do you add an element to a List in
>   Scala 2.7.5, without creating a new
>   List and without using a deprecated
>   solution.

Use `::`:

```
val newList = element :: oldList
```

Or, if `list` is a `var`,

```
list ::= element
```

It does not create a new `List` (though, it creates a new `::`, also known as *cons*), and it adds an element to it.

If you want to append elements to a sequence without creating a new sequence, use a mutable data structure.

Comment: This actually `prepends` an element to a list, which is different than an `append` operation.

Comment: @opensas `List` is immutable, so you can't change it. You have to assign a new list to the variable, which requires using an assignment.

Comment: oops, I thought that if list was a var it wasn't an immutable anymore

Answer (score 24):

You could use a `ListBuffer`, which provides constant time append:

```
val buffer = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Int]
buffer += 1
buffer += 2
val list = buffer.toList
```

Answer (score 17):

It's worth pointing out that `List` has a very specific meaning in scala, which is not equivalent to the `java.util.List` interface. `List` is a sealed, abstract class representing a *recursive* data-structure which has a *head* and a *tail*. (There do exist Java list-like structures in scala, some of which are mutable.)

Scala's `List`s are **immutable**; modifying a list in any way is not possible, although you can create a new list be prepending to an existing one (which gives a new object back). Even though they are immutable, the structure is no more *expensive* in terms of object creation than, say, appending to a `java.util.LinkedList`

The `+` method has been deprecated for good reason because it is inefficient; instead use:

```
val newList = theList ::: List(toAppend)
```

I suppose a different way would be to prepend with 2 reversals:

```
val newList = (toAppend :: theList.reverse).reverse
```

I doubt this is any more efficient! In general, if I want *append* behaviour, I use *prepend* and then `reverse` (at the point of needing to access the list):

```
val newList = toAppend :: theList
//much later! I need to send the list somewhere...
target ! newList.reverse
```

Comment: This is an argumentation, why the question might be a bad one. But it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It exactly answers the question. The questioner has asked how to add to a list without creating a new list. This is impossible! Perhaps you should expand on why you have downvoted my (correct) answer

Comment: Jens, to apply your own reasoning, you have not answered the question either since it asks how to append to a `List`, not a `LinkedList` or `ListBuffer`, neither of which derive from `List`. (Yet your answer is still useful.)

Comment: I like the append the existing list to a new list of one item approach!

Answer (score 2):

The `+=` method on a list is deprecated because it adds an element to the tail, which is expensive. The least expensive way of adding an element to a list is to add to the head using `::=`.

So the deprecation warning is a subtle hint that you should redesign your program to work by prepending instead of appending:

```
scala> var l = List(1, 2, 3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l ::= 4

scala> l
res1: List[Int] = List(4, 1, 2, 3)
```

(Note that `::=` and `+=` on a `var` are not real methods, but sugar for `l = l :: elem`, etc)

Comment: But is `l` still the same list?  Also you are prepending, not appending.

Comment: Well then you did not answer the question  :)

Comment: Often the real solution to the underlying problem is not a direct answer to the original question.

Comment: @leppie The questions asks how one adds an element. The question title mentions append. So he answered the question, though not the title. :-)

Comment: @Daniel: No, he asked how to do it without creating a new list.

Comment: leppie, if you are aware of how Scala's syntactic sugar allows apparently mutable-style operations on immutable objects that are vars, then it makes sense to interpret that part of the question as "without *explicitly* creating a new list". And in case he/she wasn't aware of that, I have mentioned it too.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:
http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/collection/mutable/SingleLinkedList.html#append%28This%29

Or this:
http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.html#%2B%3A%28A%29

The basic trick is to use a mutable List (or class with similiar functionality)

Comment: that is possible, but goes against the spirit of scala

Answer (score 1):

The following is not true for certain operations List implementation. Thanks to sschaef for the correction.

---

A very important point that I haven't seen mentioned here is that creating a new collection from another collection necessarily isn't as expensive in Scala as it is in Java. This concept is called persistence. Daniel Spiewak lays it out in his article, http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/scala-collections-for-the-easily-bored-part-1.

Here is a snippet of the relevant section,

> Of course, the natural question which comes to mind is, what about performance?  If each invocation actually creates a brand new Set for every recursive call, doesn’t that require a lot of inefficient object copying and heap operations?  Well, as it turns out, this isn’t really the case.  Yes, a new instance must be created at each turn, which is is a comparatively expensive operation on the JVM, but almost nothing is being copied.  All of Scala’s immutable data structures have a property known as persistence, which means that you don’t copy the data out of the old container when creating a new, you just have the new reference the old and treat all of its contents as if they were its own.

So while it will be less expensive to use a mutable list it isn't as much of a concern as it is under Java.

Comment: This is only true for immutable data structures whose contents can be shared because of existing references to them. This is not the case when you want to append an element to Scalas List, since it is a single linked list and no reference to the last element exists. This means that each element must be copied in order to append an element which is O(n). In contrast prepending an element is O(1) because the new element can point to the old list without copying anything (this is what your quote describes).

Comment: @sschaef, ah thank you for correcting me, I am new to Scala and still figuring all this out.

Comment: To your edit: It is true for List, but not for all operations. The same with other data structures...